# make chart label with textbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am drawing a chart in c# windows form application. I was wondering if you can make the labels of x and y Axis like a textbox so the user would be able to change it him/herself.

write now I have the code like this for my X axis:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = gearWidth;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 2;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = ("Width (mm)");
```

now the title is fixed and is "Width (mm)" all the time, but I want the title to be dynamic so the user will change it during runtime and e.g. change it to "Length of gear"

Comment: You can make a `label` and bind an `OnClick-Event` to it. The method handling the event opens a pop up which contains a `textBox`. On closing the value of the textBox is used as title for the label.

Comment: You can create `TextBox` somewhere else on your form or in a settings page and then after changing the value of those text boxes, change titles on chart.